# How can I view or monitor AWS CodeStar deployed Spring projects application log?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-codestar, awsdeploy

After deploying spring project in server like tomcat, i can view or monitor applications log using bellow ways:

- just **tail -f catalina.out** command on `catalina.out` file
- View the applications configured log file from specific folder.

In AWS CodeStar it is just deploying code from my repository. But where and how can I view the log file?

I am new in AWS environment. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked it in cloudwatch already?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Actually i am novice in AWS. Please give me some link or way to work